# Query Dictionaries with PySwip (Python-Prolog)

Tags: python, prolog, swi-prolog

This may be a super niche question. I'm able to query dictionaries in Prolog like so:

```
Customer = customer{age: 26, name: jodie}.
```

which yields

```
Customer = customer{age:26, name:jodie}.
```

However, I'm getting garbled results with PySwip, where the following

```py
from pyswip import Prolog
prolog = Prolog()
list(prolog.query('Customer = customer{age: 26, name: jodie}'))
```

outputs

```
[{'Customer': 'dict(customer, jodie, name, 26, age)'}]
```

How can I make PySwip give me a list of dicts of dicts, such as

```
[{'Customer': {name: 'jodie', age: 26}}]
```

Comment: What do you expect your "list of dicts of dicts" to look like?

Comment: @ScottHunter Edited my answer.

Comment: That isn't a "list of dicts of dicts": its a list of dicts of strings.

Comment: @ScottHunter Oops my bad. Edited again.

Comment: And how is one to tell which values are strings are which are not?

Comment: @ScottHunter I assume you mean "how to turn `[{'Customer': 'dict(customer, jodie, name, 26, age)'}]` into `[{'Customer': {name: 'jodie', age: 26}}]`". I'm thinking a solution, if any, will probably exist on the PySwip side instead of by parsing the problematic results into Python dictionaries.